# Efficient way to review formulas that generate named objects in R

Tags: r, usability

If I have a named object (in my case a named plot) in R, is there an efficient way to double check the formula that generated it? As of now I am scrolling back through the console, but I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way.

For example, at the start of my project I input

```
Boxplot <- ggplot(plotting input) + geom_boxplot(plotting input)
```

Now I can call Boxplot by name to plot it, but I want to be able to efficiently review my ggplot input. Is there a tool to do this?

Comment: for `ggplot2` plots, you may find `gghost` useful ([cran link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggghost/) and [github page](https://github.com/jonocarroll/ggghost) )

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thank you, this looks great.

Comment: I found that "edit" is also an efficient way to review named plotting inputs, and also adds the benefit allowing editing.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can see the elements of `Boxplot` using:

```
names(Boxplot)
```

So you can see, for example, the input data using:

```
Boxplot$data
```

Or the parameters and type of the plot using:

```
Boxplot$layers
```

Comment: You might mention that `str` is a useful tool for looking inside R objects.